# Adding load balancing completely slowed down my server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, load-balancing

I have decided to scale a service and added load balancing using NGINX upstream.

My Setup

```
upstream main {
  server example1.com:8909 weight=1;
  server example2.com:8909 weight=1;
  ...
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass  http://main;
  }
}
```

And Apache2 handles the request on each server. The load balancing server also houses an apache instance, the code and the main database (they will move eventually).

The code folder (`/var/www/`) is shared as nfs on the network. Also the other servers access the database remotely.

When I access, only when i hit the server housing the loadbalancer and database that it is instant. When I hit any other server it takes like 5-8 seconds to load.

Note: The hosting service does not support private ip, so they are all on public ip for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was considering deleting the question but in case it helps someone who has the same problem.

I am hosting my website on digitalocean.com and turns out they don't support private Ip yet. So when creating my new cluster of servers I added it by mistake in a different data center. ( the ping was returning 75ms response as opposed to the less than 1ms they promised). As soon as I realized that and moved my application the same data center the site speed was back to normal.